# Visual Studio Mac - Generate Deps file Failed

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-mac

I tried to run .Net Core application in Visual Studio Mac. DB migration worked successfully. But the following error is popping up. Can anyone help me to solve this.

> /usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/2.2.401/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets(5,5): Error MSB4018: The "GenerateDepsFile" task failed unexpectedly.
>   System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type of field
>   'Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.DependencyContextBuilder:_filteredPackages'
>   (12) due to: Could not resolve type with token 01000027 from typeref
>   (expected class 'NuGet.Packaging.Core.PackageIdentity' in assembly
>   'NuGet.Packaging, Version=5.2.0.3, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35') assembly:NuGet.Packaging,
>   Version=5.2.0.3, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
>   type:NuGet.Packaging.Core.PackageIdentity member:(null)   at
>   Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.TaskBase.Execute () [0x00000] in
>   <73c82f66c8c94b8d8d3314a5e98a0984>:0    at
>   Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute
>   () [0x00023] in
>   /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2018-08/external/bockbuild/builds/msbuild-15/src/Build/BackEnd/TaskExecutionHost/TaskExecutionHost.cs:573
>   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.ExecuteInstantiatedTask
>   (Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost taskExecutionHost,
>   Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.Logging.TaskLoggingContext taskLoggingContext,
>   Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskHost taskHost,
>   Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ItemBucket bucket,
>   Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionMode howToExecuteTask) [0x001f6]
>   in
>   /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2018-08/external/bockbuild/builds/msbuild-15/src/Build/BackEnd/Components/RequestBuilder/TaskBuilder.cs:784
>   (MSB4018) (Ammboo.Core.Infrastructure)

Thanks in Advance

Comment: What version of VS Mac and Mono are you using? The error looks like a mismatch between the NuGet version being used by Mono's MSBuild and the .NET Core SDK. My guess is that you are using VS Mac 8.2 and Mono 6.0.0.319, which do not support NuGet 5.2 as far as I am aware. Using the older .NET Core 2.2.301 SDK should work.

Comment: I am using Visual Studio Version 8.0.6 (build 4), Mono 5.18.1.3 (2018-08/fdb26b0a445) (64-bit), NuGet Version: 4.8.2.5835 and .NET Core
Runtime Versions:
 2.2.6
 2.1.9
 2.1.2
 2.0.5

Answer (score 0):

Your Mono and Visual Studio for Mac version do not support the versions of the .NET Core SDK you are trying to use.

Mono 5.18.1.3 only supports .NET Core 2.1.507, or earlier versions, or .NET Core 2.2.108 or earlier.

Later .NET Core sdk versions are not supported due to incompatibilities between NuGet versions.

You will have to [uninstall the newer SDK versions](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/blob/master/scripts/obtain/uninstall/dotnet-uninstall-pkgs.sh). Visual Studio for Mac 8.0 does not support using a [global.json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/core/tools/global-json) to use a specific SDK version.

Comment: Will uninstalling the visual studio and reinstalling will fix my issue?

Comment: You will need to uninstall the .NET Core SDK. Uninstalling Visual Studio for Mac will not fix the problem. There is a link to an uninstall script in the answer. There is also a [manual way to remove the .NET Core SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/versions/remove-runtime-sdk-versions?tabs=macos).